# Sharing vectors between two class instances

Tags: c++, vector

I am getting the values of the vector size as `1` and `0` I know there are 2 different instances but I want it to be common between both the instances

I am not sure what would be the right approach need some insights on what will suffice in my case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Fruit
{
  public:
   Fruit(std::vector<int>& number);
   Fruit();
  int numOfApple();
  private:
  std::vector<int> number;
};

Fruit::Fruit() {}

class Apple
{
  public:
  Apple();
  Apple(Fruit &fruit);
  int appleCount();

  private:
  Fruit fruit;

};

Apple::Apple() {}

Apple::Apple(Fruit &fruit):fruit(fruit) {}

int Fruit::numOfApple()
{
  std::cout<<"vector size is"<<number.size()<<std::endl;
  for (auto& fruz : number) {
   std::cout<<"do nothing"<<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}


int Apple::appleCount()
{
  fruit.numOfApple();
  return 0;
}

Fruit::Fruit(std::vector<int>& number):number(number) {}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> fru;
  fru.push_back(1);

  Fruit fruit1(fru);

  Apple apple(fruit1);
  fruit1.numOfApple(); // the size of the vector here is 1

  // Now try to simulate server code

  Fruit fruit2;
  fruit2.numOfApple(); // the size of vector in this is 0

  return 0;
}
```

Output

> ```
> ./a.out
> vector size is1
> do nothing
> vector size is0
> ```

Comment: Do you want `Fruit::number` to be a single vector that is shared and can be modified by every `Fruit` during the lifetime of your program? If so, you can make it `static`.

Comment: I think you just want to make the vector static in fruit and remove `Fruit(std::vector<int>& number)`.

Comment: ATM it would suffice to keep a reference as member variable: `std::vector<int>& number;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you plz comment on this how I can get the `handler` https://ibb.co/niqDnT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `std::shared_ptr` for this purpose. It lives as long as any of the objects referencing it are alive and allows multiple objects to share ownership of its contents.

```
class Fruit
{
  Fruit::Fruit()
    : number(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>())
  {}

  Fruit(std::vector<int>& numberNew)
    : number(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(numberNew))
  {}

  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> number;
}
```

Now when your class is copied, the copy of the `shared_ptr` will not copy the vector but just refer to the same one and deal with all lifetime management for you.

```
int Fruit::numOfApple()
{
  std::cout << "vector size is" << number->size() << std::endl;
  for (auto& fruz : *number) {
   std::cout << "do nothing" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I strongly advise against making anything `static` unless that is absolutely necessary. It is not necessary here, and you can prevent future growth pains by going for a proper solution right now.

Comment: I don't believe this will fix the `fruit2` having an empty vector problem. I am talking about: `Fruit fruit2;` then `fruit2.numOfApple();` in `main()` the OP expects `fruit2` to share the same vector from `fruit1` without passing the vector.